# How do I call my Django REST API endpoint with CURL?

Tags: python, django, curl, django-rest-framework

I want to call my Django REST Framework API using cURL, but it doesn't do anything.

My URL is like "https://MYURL/api/seedevents?secret=SECRET". In postman this works and returns a 201 Created HTTP response. If I call using CURL for example "curl -XGET 'https://MYURL/api/seedevents?secret=SECRET', then it doesn't do anything at all. I can see the request come in in the logs, but it just doesn't do anything.

Please can someone advise me what I can do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess it's probably missing some headers.

A helpful tip is to extract the curl command from Postman, on the right side you will find a code symbol as the below screenshot, that will make the same request in different form, choose cURL and use the command (make sure to use `data` instead of `data-raw` in case you have a payload)

[image]

Also add `-vvv` after `curl` to debug the curl

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for. I will try that in my crontab file now.